# How to difference similar methods that vary by parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm defining a js file with similar methods but they can vary by business logic depending of the selected country in the app, this is only a little demo of what I'm doing:

```
HTML

Date: <span id="date"></span>
<br>
<p>Current country: <span id="country"></span></p>

JS

(function() {

    // data retrieved from somewhere: 1.Germany, 2.France, etc ...
    var countryId = 1;

    function myModule() {
        this.common = {
            getCountryName: function() {
                return "I'm the whole world!";
            },
            getDate: function() {
                return new Date();
            }
        };

        this.germany = {
            getCountryName: function() {
                return "I'm Germany!";
            }
        };

        this.france = {
            getCountryName: function() {
                return "I'm France!";
            }
        };

        return {
            common: this.common,
            germany: this.germany,
            france: this.france
        }
    }

    var fn = function(fnName) {
        var country, module, exists;

        country = getCountry(countryId);
        module = new myModule();
        exists = !!module[country] && !!module[country][fnName];

        return exists ? module[country][fnName] : module.common[fnName];
    };

    function getCountry(countryId) {
        var countryName = "";
        switch (countryId) {
            case 1:
                countryName = "germany";
                break;
            case 2:
                countryName = "france";
                break;
        };

        return countryName;
    }

    window.demoModule = {
        getDate: fn("getDate"),
        getCountryName: fn("getCountryName")
    }
}());

(function() {
    $(document).ready(initialize);

    function initialize() {
        $("#date").text(demoModule.getDate().toLocaleDateString());
        $("#country").text(demoModule.getCountryName());
    }

}());
```

I'm want to do something like this because I need different functionality depending of the selected country but it seems a bit complex, Do you know a better or simple way for handle something like this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/odsu8oLf/5/

Regards

Comment: What is issue with `javascript` at Question?

Comment: There is no issue, I'm looking for a better way to handle the described scenario

Comment: Well, the way with multiple modules that are dynamically selected is *totally appropriate* for the described scenario. Sure, it is complex, but this complexity seems to be inherent. The particular example code you've shown could be dramatically simplified given the `countryId` is static (unlike the comment that says "*data retrieved from somewhere*"), but it all depends on what you are able to simplify and what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you aren't doing something as trivial as returning the country name (any actual data should be stored on the DB, not in your front end code), the best solution will come down to what you are actually trying to do. Here's two options based on two different scenarios:

**Scenario 1**
You have mostly the same logic with a few country specific exceptions:
`switch` on `countryId`

```js
function doLogic(countryId) {
  // do any possible common logic here
  switch (countryId) {
    case 1: return "France"
    case 2: return "Germany"
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: return "special logic for 3 4 and 5"
    default: return "same for all the rest"
  } 
}
console.log(doLogic(1))
console.log(doLogic(4))
console.log(doLogic(9999))
```

**Scenario 2**
You have wildly different logic for each country
extract differences into an object of `countryId` -> logic fn

```js
var COUNTRY_LOGIC = {
  1 () { return "France" },
  2 () { return "Germany" },
  3 () { return "whatever"}
}


function doLogic(countryId) {
  // do any possible common logic here
  var countryLogicFn = COUNTRY_LOGIC[countryId]
  if (typeof countryLogicFn === "function") {
    return countryLogicFn()
  }
  return "do some other thing"
}

console.log(doLogic(1))
console.log(doLogic(3))
console.log(doLogic(9999))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I omit some of your code but I think you could simplify more modular like this:

```
    var Country = (function() {
        return {
        countryId : 3,
      germany   : 'Im Germany',
      france : 'Im France', 
     initialize : function(countryId)
     {
            $("#date").text(this.getDate().toLocaleDateString());
        $("#country").text(this.getCountry(countryId));
     },
      getDate: function() 
      {
            return new Date();
      },
      getCountry : function(countryId)
      {
            var countryName = "";
        switch (countryId) {
            case 1:
                countryName = "germany";
                break;
            case 2:
                countryName = "france";
                break;
             default:
                    countryName = "I'm the whole world!";
        };
        return countryName;
        }
    };
})();
Country.initialize();


  Country.initialize(1);
```